# Why form in RCL(Razor Class Library) no working in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code in front-end:

```
@model Sample.Models.VistorModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
        <form id="ContactForm" asp-action="Contact">            
            <div>
                <h3>@Localizer["Name"]</h3>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Name" placeholder="@Localizer["NameHint"]" />
            <div>
                <h3>@Localizer["Phone"]</h3>
                <span asp-validation-for="Phone"></span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Phone" placeholder="@Localizer["PhoneHint"]" type="tel" />
            <button type="submit">@Localizer["Sumit"]</button>
        </form>
```

Here is the model:

```
public class VistorModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        [RegularExpression(@"((\d{11})|^((\d{7,8})|(\d{4}|\d{3})-(\d{7,8})|(\d{4}|\d{3})-(\d{7,8})-(\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})|(\d{7,8})-(\d{4}|\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1}))$)", ErrorMessageResourceName = "NotAPhoneNumber", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Sample.Resources.Views.Contact.Contact))]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    [Route("{culture}/[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Contact.html")]
        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("Contact.html")]
        public IActionResult Contact(Models.VistorModel Vistor)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I add a breakpoint in the controller and found the `public IActionResult Contact(Models.VistorModel Vistor)` never be invoked while I clicked the button. It always invokes the `public IActionResult Contact()` only.

I made another test to migrate all the code above to a brand new asp.net Core MVC project and it works well.

What's wrong with this?

---

To Fei Han, here is the source html code in browser:

```
<form id="ContactForm" asp-action="Contact" method="post">
            <div>
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Name" placeholder="Your name">
            <div>
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <span asp-validation-for="Phone"></span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Phone" placeholder="Your phone" type="tel">
            <button type="submit">Sumit</button>
        </form>
```

What's more, I render the RCL in asp.net core project like this:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Contact/Contact.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `public IActionResult Contact(Models.VistorModel Vistor)` never be invoked while I clicked the button. It always invokes the `public IActionResult Contact()`only.

Please try to set `method="post"` for your form tag, like below.

```
<form id="ContactForm" method="post" asp-action="Contact">
```

***Update:***

To make the Form tag helper etc available to view(s) in RCL, we can add following code in view page or Razor View Imports file.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: After I tried this way, neither public IActionResult Contact(Models.VistorModel Vistor) nor public IActionResult Contact() invoke while I clicked the button.

Comment: Have you checked the actual html source code of the form `ContactForm` in browser developer tool?

Comment: Based on your generated html source code, please try to add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in your RCL view to make the Form tag helper work.

Comment: Great! It works now! Would you please edit your answer with this code? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @MelonNG, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I have updated the reply , you can check it.